# Will there be different number of zero crossings for driving a 3 phase multipole bldc (motor) vs it being driven (generator)?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

Background

I'm working on creating circuits and code to drive 6 step bldc switching logic in a Teensy 4.0 microcontroller. I have previously got this working with an Arduino Uno. I've tried with the Teensy to get the analogue comparators working but they don't offer enough hysteresis and ive given up on that.

I've changed strategy and am now using an encoder to know the angle and want to work out the ideal geometric zero-crossing points (at speed zero) and perturb them when the speed changes.

Problem:

I need to convert from mechanical degrees 0->360 to electrical degrees to know what the ideal geometric switching points are (not pertubed by the speed, aka the switching point when speed is zero)

I've been looking online and in some book and trying to rationalise it myself. I have driven my 14 pole (7 pole pair) 3 phase bldc motor with a drill and inspected adc measurements, i see 42 total crossings.

I've seen this formula that applies to any type of multipolar electrical machine:
Electrical angle = (Number of poles / 2) * Mechanical angle

The result from the formula above seems consistant with what I have measured.

I also have found another formula:
Electrical degrees = (Mechanical degrees * Number of poles) / (Number of phases * 2)

This formula is supposedly used to convert from mechanical degrees to electrical degrees when the BLDC motor is being used as a motor. It takes into account the number of poles, phases, and commutation steps in the motor.

But the two give inconsistant results for electical angle and imply a different number of zero crossings.

Why are they different? Why would you use a different formula when driving vs using it as a generator. My intuition is failing me. Cheers

Comment: Please link the sources of those two formula.

Comment: So I got the Electrical angle = (Number of poles / 2) * Mechanical angle from various sources from the internet..... one example is this post https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-electrical-angle-and-mechanical-angle-in-rotating-electrical-machines

Comment: The other formula i am struggling to find online sources I read it in an old PDF and i cannot find an internet link for this. Sorry but I might not be able to find it! But my question still stands will there be different number of zero crossings for driving a bldc motor vs it being driven.

Comment: The number of poles / 2 is also found in this book https://dl.poweren.ir/downloads/PowerEn/Book/2018/Jun/Principles%20of%20Electric%20Machines%20and%20Power%20Electronics%20%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B4%20%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%85%20%28PowerEn.ir%29.pdf